# How can I run all functions with their corresponding arguments at once by a single `run()`?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have two files,

File 1

```
exports.run = () => {
    console.log(test.property, test2.property, etc.property)
};
exports.info = {
    name : "test"
}
```

File 2

```
const fs = require('fs');
let test;
let test2;
let etc;
test.property = "test";
test2.property = "test2";
etc.property = "etc";
let functions = new Map();
fs.readdir('./', (err, files) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    files.forEach(f => {
        let props = require(`./${f}`);
        functions.set(props.info.name, props);
    });
});
functions.get("test").run()
```

As I have it right now, I need to manually add each variable as a parameter in file 1 and in file 2 I need to manually pass each through the `.run()`. This is tedious and annoying so is there anyway that I can just scope the `.run()` so that it uses all of the current variables?

Comment: I try to understand your code, but I cannot figure out your purpose. Maybe make the code shorter and cleaner and explain the question in another way?

Comment: I have a lot of functions and I like having multiple files since it is easier and more organized and I put all of the functions into a map so it isn't as convoluted since I have many functions but for each when I call them I have to pass parameters. It would be much easier if all of these functions could just be scoped like functions that I define in the main code so is there a way to do that?

Comment: I'm trying to understand your use case here; so you have multiple modules, each with some functions on them, and you are trying to pass in values from the main script into each of these modules?

Comment: A scope is just a container of variables. Know what else is a container of variables? An object! Just put all of the things you want to pass parameters in an object and pass that one object to your functions. That way, you can add or remove variables freely without needing to go change them in multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether it's your wanted code

```
const args = {
    foo: ["a", "b"],
    bar: ["c", "d", "e"]
}

const map = new Map();


function Foo(first, second) {
    console.log(first, second)
}

function Bar(first, second, third) {
    console.log(first, second, third)
}

map.set("foo", Foo);
map.set("bar", Bar);

function run() {
    for(const key of map.keys()) {
        const func = map.get(key);
        func.apply(undefined, args[key])
    }
}

run();

// output
// a b
// c d e
```

the key point is `apply` function, which can call a *function reference* with its arguments as `apply`'s arguments. You can check out more on MDN of `apply`.

Comment: Omg, `apply`. You are a lifesaver

Comment: Glad to solve your problem. BTW, your question code is misleading, you should make it clear, i.e. there's nothing about files and modules.

Comment: It's not working, I feel like it is related to the fact that it is multiple files. If I don't use the `module.exports.run` or `exports.run` it works fine as intended but as soon as I do have them it stops working :(

Comment: what are multiple files, do you mean many functions in many modules? You can modify your question code to let me understand easier, and remember to make the code clear, just like what I posted to you.

Comment: @newbie programmer?